# Vuejs 2: how to detect img.complete property

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I have code that fetches a list of images as an object like

```
[
  { src: '/path/to/img.jpg', loaded: false },
  ...
]
```

and template that then renders them as HTML like:

```
<div
  v-for="image in alltheimages"
  :key="image.id" >
  <transition name="fade" appear>
  <img
    :src="image.src"
    v-show="image.loaded"
    @load="image.loaded = true"
    />
  </transition>
</div>
```

This works well when first loading the page; the images fade in as soon as they're loaded.

However there's a problem when the image is **already loaded in cache** because then the `@load` never fires on the new `<img>` element. In these situations I can check the DOM img tag's `.complete` property, but how can I do that in VueJS?

I've tried `v-show="this.complete || image.loaded"` but `this` just points to `window`. I thought I could use a method call and pass a reference to the element which initiated the call, but I can't find out how to do that either.

I realise I could load all the images separately with `new Image()`, bind a listenter to the `load` event before I provide `src` and from there update the data to say the thing is loaded, but that a whole lotta code and objects - be much nicer to be able to use the DOM elements Vue creates.

Comment: There's a library for this issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-images-loaded

Comment: May not be what you like, but most of my components just have a property 'mounted' which I programmatically set from false to true in the mounted lifecycle hook.  That would allow you to do something as v-show="mounted && image.loaded".  If you care about too much code, write a mixin for it?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with a directive.

```
<div
  v-for="image in alltheimages"
  :key="image.id" >
  <transition name="fade" appear>
  <img
    :src="image.src"
    v-show="image.loaded"
    v-loadedifcomplete="image"
    @load="image.loaded = true"
    />
  </transition>
</div>
```

Then in your app.

```
new Vue({
  ...
  directives: {
    loadedifcomplete: function(el, binding) {
       if (el.complete) {
         binding.value.loaded = true;
       }
    }
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: stumbled on this but can't seem to get your solution to work. the loadedifcomplete function fires, but nothing inside the `if` statement. My images successfully load, but the `complete` property remains false. What is the `@load` piece of your code? I don't believe this ever triggers for me either

Comment: Is this correct? `@load` works for new images that will trigger it when their download finishes, meanwhile `v-loadedifcomplete` is run on mount and checks whether a cached image (which exists at mount stage and would never trigger `@load`) has a `complete` attribute and sets loaded appropriately.

Comment: this is not correct

Comment: This worked outright using vue3, did't need a `:key` though

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have any luck with this method, nor with [vue-images-loaded](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-images-loaded) but [vue-onload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-onload) worked like a charm.

In main.js add:

```
import OnLoad from 'vue-onload'
Vue.use(OnLoad);
```

and on the images you are loading:

```
<img 
  class="gallery__image" 
  v-onload="[image src]"
/>
```

then just add whatever css animation you want to to occur in your stylesheet:

```
 /*loaded state*/
.gallery__image {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

 /*unloaded state*/
.gallery__image[data-src]{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

v-cloak might provide the functionality you are looking for
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how that directive can be used to provide a way to execute a function that needs to access a property of the created img element.

Answer (score -2):

You can bind to the native `onLoad` event and call any method in your component that you want.  [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1zk92coz/)

```
<div id="app">
    <img v-for="num in [1,2,3,4]"
         src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"
         :onLoad="onLoadHandler()" />
</div>


new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        onLoadHandler: function() {
            alert('hi');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is equivalent to the code in the probem above. [VueJS docs for @load / v-on-load](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)